# Target of url doesn't exist 'package:flutter/material.dart'

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to download a project from github while my project is open and this message shows to me i searched for many solutions and i didn't get any help
Target of url doesn't exist 'package:flutter/material.dart'

Comment: Maybe the dependencies arent installed. Try running 'flutter pub get' in terminal from root directory of the project that contains pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at some possible solutions in this article:

https://faizan-khan-seo-sem-smm.medium.com/solve-error-target-of-uri-doesnt-exist-package-flutter-material-dart-android-studio-flutter-ad4fbecc388